# How should I structure my time series dataframe in Python/Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

> I have a dataframe with multiple repeating series, over time.
>
> > I want to create visualizations that compare series over time, as well as with one another.
> >
> > > What is the best way to structure my data to accomplish this?

- I have thus far been trying to make smaller dataframes from this, by either dropping years or selecting only one series; using a variety of indexes, lists or series calls that refer to the multiple years, .Series, .loc or .drop etc..
- I always seem to encounter the same issues when making the actual graphs; usually relating to the years.
- My best result has been making simple bar graphs with countries on the x axis and GDP from **only** 2018 on the Y axis.

> I would like to eventually be able to have countries represented by color with 3D **plotly** graphs, wherein a series like GDP is Z (depth), Years are Y, and some other series like GNI could be X.
>
> > For now I am just aiming to make a scatterplot
> >
> > > I am also fine with using matplot, seaborn, whatever makes the most sense here.

```
Columns: [country, series, 1994, 1995, 1996, etc..]


Country Series     1994              1995           1996    ...

USA     GDP        3.12              4.13
USA     Export%    25.5              32
USA     GNI        867,123,111       989,666,123
UK      GDP        2.87              etc.
UK      Export%    43.1
UK      GNI        981,125,555
China   GDP        5.98
China   Export%    NaN
China   GNI        787,123,447
...
```

```
df1 = df.loc[df['series']== 'GDP']
time = df1['1994':'1996']

gdp_time = px.scatter(df1, x = time, y= 'series', color="country")
gdp_time.show()
```

```
#Desired Graph

gdp_time = px.scatter(df1, x = years, y= GDP, color= Countries)
gdp_time.show()
```

I find it hard to believe that I cant simply create a series that references the multiple year columns as a singular *'time'*.

**What am I missing?**

Comment: I currently receive an error when I input the middle block as seen above. Often this error relates to time not being found in the data frame.

Comment: Reference 'Tidy Dataframe'

Comment: Use Melt, Stack/Unstack, or Pivot to achieve desired 'Time' Column